# How can I place a photo on someone else's webpage when linked to from my site?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I know this is a strange thing to want to do, but...

How can I place a photo at the top of someone else's webpage ("Page B") -only- when a visitor links there from my page ("Page A")?  I have permission to do this, but with certain limitations: my code needs to be in one location on Page B, and I can't make major changes to Page B.  I cannot use Page B's server to run PHP, but I can run PHP on Page A's server.

The photo needs to open automatically with the rest of the Page B, and not require any user input to show up.

This is a unique vendor/retailer situation, so unfortunately I can't provide the urls.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "the owner of Page B will allow me to add more code to that area, but only that area"...how does this work currently?

Comment: Hi AJ, that is just the code/link for the button and it works fine right now.  I was just trying to make it clear that I can add code for the photo, but it has to be contiguous with the button code.  They don't have to have anything to do with each other function-wise, but they need to be above/below each other in Page B's html.

Comment: So you want to know how you can implement an `<img>` tag?  I'm confused...

Comment: I have re-written to question a little so that it is hopefully a bit more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you'd do something like:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://www.yoursite.com/referringpage.html')
{
    printf('<img src="yourbutton.png">');
}
?>
```

Which is very limited because:

- It will only work for a referring single page (referringpage.html) and not otherreferringpage.html
- It will only work for a single landing page.  If the user navigates off of the page, then back (not through browser's back), the button will not show up.

To solve the first you could do a substring of the referrer, e.g.

```
<?php
if(substring($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],0,24) == 'http://www.yoursite.com/')
{
    printf('<img src="yourbutton.png">');
}
?>
```

To solve the second you could set session variables (except then you'd need access to the very top of the "outermost" page -- which doesn't sound like an option.)

Comment: Hi, I haven't been very clear, I'm afraid.  The button is done and working fine.  It is actually irrelevant to my question, except that Page B's owner wants all of my code in the same place when he looks at his html. And since I already have the code for the button, the code for the image needs to be close to it.

Comment: So let me see if I get this now, you want code that will: (a) all be in one spot, (b) insert a button somewhere regardless of where the hit came from, and (c) insert an image at the top of the page if the hit came from a certain site.  Sound right?  Also, are you able to add any code (including PHP markup and Javascript)?  If you are, this is doable.

Comment: You're getting closer!  The button already exists.  It does not need to be added or changed, or otherwise considered at all.  I would like to insert an image at the top of the page if the hit came from a certain site.  I would like the code for this image to be in the same spot as the code for the button - that is the only reason the button was mentioned.  I can add any kind of PHP/Javascript code to Page A, and to the page/server the image is on, but front-end only code to Page B.

Comment: Well you should find out whether you can insert php code into the button code -- otherwise a pure javascript implementation is possible but annoying. (I'm assuming you can insert js code into the buttom code -- you should verify this as well).

Comment: PHP would be fine, but any PHP code would have to run on Page A's server.  Once again, the button on Page B doesn't need any changes and doesn't have anything to do with the image in any way.  The code for the image just needs to be co-located with/near it.  Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: So is PHP a possibility under those conditions?  If not, what are your thoughts on the annoying javascript?

Comment: I mean, it depends what your partner allows you to post.  So really its up to him.  I'll work out what needs to be done to add the image.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It is my understanding that just about anything is allowed as long as it doesn't use his server.  It would be helpful if it didn't make his page load too slowly, and if he could upload all the code to his site in one place (next to/with the button code) and at one time.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the design of the page.
Lets say,

1. If the page is divided into frames, then you can use iframe.
2. if It's a single page, try have a separation with div tag. Insert the html into Div Tag.

If the above two points won't help you,give an idea of how the page is designed

Comment: I'm not sure either of these solutions check the referring page.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple answer would be to write a html page (lets call it linkPage) that has the image/text/div or whatever you want to display on the top and then include an iframe that would cover the rest of the page using css.  You could pass the page you are linking to as a GET or POST parameter to the linkPage and then set the src of the iframe to that url.

There are probably other ways of doing this that are more complicated / seamless but this would be the easiest, quickest way to get it done.